# OOP: Class A and Class B is depend together. Is this well design?

Tags: oop, uml

I have read some UML class diagram. I see some UML design this way:

For example: there are two class: class Student and class Transcript. Every student has a transcript, and every transcript is together with a student. So, class Student and class Transcript is depend together. So, is this a well design class ?

If not, how can we fix this. And if this is OK, how can I implemented this relation well ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a very good design: apparently, you want `student.transcript.student == student` and `transcript.student.transcript == transcript` to be true at any given moment, right? But what about Students without Transcripts? Transcripts without Students? If those are prohibited, you may end in a funny situation: you'll have to create corresponding `Student` and `Transcript` at the same time!

Well, in database area, this is usually modeled with three tables (which may or may not correspond directly to actual physical tables):

```
TABLE Student ( studentId ID PRIMARY KEY, ... )

TABLE Transcript ( transcriptId ID PRIMARY KEY, ... )

TABLE StudentTranscriptLink (
    studentId ID NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES Student(studentId),
    transcriptID Id NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES Transcript(transcriptId)
) PRIMARY KEY ( studentId, transcriptId )
```

The `UNIQUE` constraints ensure that if you take Student, get its Transcript, and get that Transcript's Student, you return to the original Student you started with; the same is true with `Transcript->Student->Transcript` navigation.

In the OOP world you probably would have some sort of `StudentTranscriptDispatcher` with `List<Pair<Student, Transcript>>` inside, and methods for turning `Student` into `Transcript` and back.

However, such bi-directional relationships are... unusual. It's basically having one large object sliced in two halves -- but still keeping those halves tied together *very* tightly. Why would you do this? It doesn't remove any complexity, on the contrary: it introduces new, artificial complexity which wasn't there before.

Comment: Yeah, you're right when it comes to database design. Not so much for OO design, however. I'd say having a distinct Student and Transcript object may well be a valid design.

Comment: Yes, but usually you wouldn't have Transcript pointing to a Student: I doubt there is any Transcript-specific method which depends on Student. The dependencies ain't introduced just to sew your program together with double stitches.

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably think about here is navigability. It sounds like the relationship is entirely appropriate, however, do you ever have to navigate from `Transcript` to `Student`? If not, your relationship is not bi-directional and `Transcript` is no longer dependent on `Student`. Do you always locate a `Student` first and then a `Transcript`?

To be honest, I wouldn't worry about it too much. If it works for you - go with it!